# can I use double and int parameter at the same time in the array?

Tags: java, arrays

I don't know why x make an error which is in the array. -line 80,96 [image: 1]

```java
public static double naiveSine(double x, int n) {
    //Implement this method
 
    double sum;
    double[][] NAIVE_SINE = new double[x][n];

    if (n < 0) {
        System.out.println("ERROR");
    } else {
        sum = 0;
        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
            double term = 1;
            for (int j = 1; j < 2*i - 1; j++){
                term = term * (x/j);
                                                    }
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    sum = sum - term;
                } else {
                    sum = sum + term;
                }
            }
            NAIVE_SINE[x][n] = sum;
        }
        
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What error does x make?

Comment: Because you cannot use doubles as array indices. The error message probably says exactly that.

Comment: What if `x` is `2.5`? What does an array with two and a half elements look like?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo its Harry Potter logic. `platform[9.75]`

Comment: If the method only returns `0` as a result, no calculations are needed.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use doubles as indices for java primitive arrays.

double[][] NAIVE_SINE = new double[x][n];

x & n must be integers.

Your multi-dimensional array itself will store doubles but, not the indices. Below is an example of an array that would have dimensions 3x3.

```
1.0  1.1  1.2

1.1  1.2  1.3

1.2  1.3  1.4
```

There might be a way using the precision (max # of decimal places) of a double value to determine placement in a multi-dimensional array but, storing those values would not look pretty